# Convert DateTime to UK format

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert the date "01/22/2013 10:00:00" to "22/01/2013 10:00:00" and my method doesn't recognise my date string.

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM dd yyyy h:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            StartDate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
 dt = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "MMM dd yyyy h:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            EndDate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

I am getting this error:

> System.FormatException - String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

What is the correct string format for ParseExact?

Comment: It's easy to see that the string should be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` even without looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 19):

Your date formatting is wrong, for the US it would be `01/22/2013 10:00:00` which is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. For the UK it would be `dd/MM/yyyy` etc.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Note I am assuming a 24 hour clock here which is why I use `HH`. If you wanted a twelve hour clock you'd need `hh` but then you should also put AM/PM etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            StartDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Notice the change to format string of `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var str = "01/22/2013 10:00:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
var res = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.WriteLine("22/01/2013 10:00:00" == res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using slashes and you have "seconds" part in your date string. You need to change the format provided in the `ParseExact` method:

```
string StartDate = "01/22/2013 10:00:00";            
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
StartDate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: `hh` is incorrect, should be `HH`.

Comment: It works because 10 is valid. Try using 23 and see what happens.

Comment: but UK time uses am/pm afaik?